# StreamReader Turkish Character Encoding

Tags: asp.net, encoding, streamreader, cultureinfo

How can I fix this problem?

```
string icerik;

WebRequest istek = HttpWebRequest.Create(adres);
istek.Proxy = null;
WebResponse cevap = istek.GetResponse();

CultureInfo tr = new CultureInfo("tr-TR");

StreamReader gelenBilgi = new StreamReader(cevap.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding(tr.TextInfo.ANSICodePage));
icerik = gelenBilgi.ReadToEnd();

htmlDoc.LoadHtml(icerik);
```

I tried some methods to solve the problem but didn't work.
For example;

```
StreamReader gelenBilgi = new StreamReader(cevap.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-9"));
```

or

```
StreamReader gelenBilgi = new StreamReader(cevap.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1254"));
```

or

```
StreamReader gelenBilgi = new StreamReader(cevap.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: What is htmlDoc? Does it have a header to accept different encodings?

Comment: private static HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem. This method helped me solve the Turkish character encoding.

```
            string content;
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(cevap.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-9");
                Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
                byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(sr.ReadToEnd());
                byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, iso, utfBytes);
                content = iso.GetString(isoBytes);
            }
```